# How some of fb apps runs on normal http server

Tags: php, mysql, facebook, http

I am very much enthusiastic in fb app development, but from 1st oct 2011 it has been declared by fb that to run fb apps we need https:// server. So it was a sad news for me, because i have normal http:// server and am a student and my previous active apps are getting closed.

But i have some question, recently from last few days i noticed some apps are runs from normal server too like,
http://whaddapp.com/ one of them, and many more,
how is that possible??

Someone please guide me in right direction, is there in hope for me??

Comment: What kind of App , you are building using facebook APi's , please post it here , so that it helps us to analyze

Comment: like you can check,
http://apps.facebook.com/djfbmltest
while am disabling the sandbox mode, it gives alert 4o4 page not found.

Answer (score 1):

I believe the HTTPS requirement is for apps that run within the Facebook frame.

You can purchase and install a SSL certificate at a rather low cost - If you install it yourself I've seen them for $10/yr + dedicated IP charges from your host. If you are using a shared environment your host may also already have a SSL certificate and you just need to use their domain.

Comment: the above link i have post, all the app are runs on facebook frame, just do click one of them. and secondly i know about ssl, but how does this apps are running successfully??

Comment: They only redirect through Facebook for permissions I think - If you click "Go to App" it goes back to the website.

Comment: i did't get ur point, by clicking on use this app, it goes inside fb successfully from my end.

Comment: Click "Use This App", It'll redirect to Facebook. From there click "Go to App". It'll go back to the original website. They are using one of the SDK's to fetch an access token with the permissions they require. Being inside the Facebook frame is merely a authentication step.

Comment: and it does work on http:// right?? could you please guide me, how does it works??

Comment: Sorry for the delay - Christmas.

Check out the example Facebook gives: https://github.com/facebook/facebook-php-sdk/blob/master/examples/example.php

Answer (score 0):

After looking at your problem , I could find some of the options that are available , these options are cost free , you don't need to pay any thing extra to achieve this

**You can go with Open SSL**

Create a self-signed cert using openssl, and install it on your web-framework. However, most browsers throw warnings on self-signed certs and adding the exceptions is not intuitive. Chrome needs some configuration, as described [here](http://www.robpeck.com/2010/10/google-chrome-mac-os-x-and-self-signed-ssl-certificates/). Safari lets you continue, but doesn't show output on Canvas. Firefox seems to let you add exceptions and does show the result correctly.

Still lots of information and options ( low cost ) are available [here](https://github.com/shamiksharma/myblog/wiki/Building-Facebook-Apps-with-SSL)

NOTE :- if your intention is to just keep up your enthusiasm , these solutions will definitely help . But for building any commercial application . you need to go for a commercial SSL certificate and a hosting server .